# Does the interrupt status of an interrupted Jetty server thread get reset before returning to the thread pool?

Tags: java, jetty, threadpool

When an interrupted Jetty thread returns to the thread pool, does a cleanup mechanism unset the interrupt flag if not already unset? Is there any provision to ensure that the thread pool does not contain any threads with the interrupt status set?

Comment: How does a Jetty thread get interrupted?  (Jetty itself doesn't do that for reasons of Servlet Spec and I/O cleanup)

Comment: I see this method http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/8.1.17.v20150415/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/util/thread/QueuedThreadPool.html#interruptThread(long).

Comment: Jetty 8 is [EOL (End of Life)](https://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/jetty-announce/msg00069.html)

Comment: Apologies, I'm using 9
http://archive.eclipse.org/jetty/9.1.1.v20140108/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/util/thread/QueuedThreadPool.html#interruptThread(long)

Comment: That's a generic interrupt for generic thread usage.  Are you attempting to interrupt a thread used for an request processing? (if so, that's not supported since Jetty 8+ due to above mentioned Servlet Spec and I/O cleanup reasons)